# Definite integral of $(\sin (x)/x)^{100}$

Tags: calculus, integration, approximation

I'm interested in evaluating or (accurately) approximating the definite integral

$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi  (\sin (x) /x)^{100}\; \text{d}x .$$

Any ideas would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Why do you need such a weird result? I got $0.4335090113908$

Comment: It's more curiosity than really needing the result. I noticed that (sin x/x)^n for large n looks similar to a Gaussian and was wondering if one can derive a general expression for n for this integral. I'm more interested in the method for deriving a result/approximation than the actual numerical value.

Comment: It is very complicated! The result of the indefinite integrale is 4 pages long and even using *Mathematica* it's impossible to simplify. A Gaussian has an area of 1 on $(-\infty,+\infty)$, which is true for an exponent between $18$ and $19$.

Comment: $\displaystyle\approx \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-\,{50 \over 3}\,x^{2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x  = {1 \over 5}\sqrt{3\pi \over 2} \approx 0.4342
$ by Laplace Method.

Comment: @user810643 $\displaystyle {\sqrt{6\pi} \over n^{1/2}} - {3\sqrt{6\pi} \over 20}\,{1 \over n^{3/2}}$

Comment: @user810643 With $\displaystyle n = 100$, you get $\displaystyle {1997\sqrt{6\pi} \over 20000} = 0.433509511605858\ldots$

Comment: @user810643 [Laplace's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method).

Comment: @Felix Marin, sorry, how do you see that the integral is approximately

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-\frac{50}{3} x^2) dx$ ?

Comment: @user810643 $\displaystyle\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left[{\sin\left(x\right) \over x}\right]^{100}\mathrm{d}x = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}
\exp\left(100\ln\left(\sin\left(x\right) \over x\right)\right)\,\mathrm{d}x \sim
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(100\ln\left(1 - { x^{2} \over 6}\right)\right)\,\mathrm{d}x =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(100\left[-\,{x^{2} \over 6}\right]\right)\,\mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: @Felix Marin, thank you, that is very helpful.

One thing I'm not following, though, is how you get the subleading term $-\frac{3\sqrt{6\pi}}{20} \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$ ?